# Parsing response Facebook iOS sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, json, parsing, sdk

Could you help me to parse response correctly:
Parser in - (void)request:(FBRequest *) request didLoad:(id)result:

```
case education:{
        NSArray *arrayRsult = [[result objectForKey:@"education"] objectForKey:@"school"];
        for (NSDictionary *placeForResults in arrayRsult){
            NSString *output = [placeForResults objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"%@", output);
        }
    }
        break;
```

My request:

```
- (IBAction)eduacation:(id)sender {
currentApiCall = education;
FacebookInfoGetterAppDelegate *delegate = (FacebookInfoGetterAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=education" andDelegate:self];
}
```

But it returns array with nulls. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to set up rights for this - "user_education_history"

I corrected code for your parsing part because your receive dictionary with key education that consists array of your schools.

```
NSArray *arrayRsult = [result objectForKey:@"education"];
for (NSDictionary *placeForResults in arrayRsult){
    NSString *output = [[placeForResults objectForKey:@"school"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", output);
}
```

it works for me.